# Jquery selector question for form labels

Tags: jquery, label, selector

I'm trying to make a selector using form labels.

```
$("label:not[for='other']")
$("label[for='other']")

<label for="other">
<label for="somethingElse">
```

If someone selects the label for 'other', do something.  If they pick a label for anything that isn't 'other' do something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "select" or "pick" a label?

Comment: @peter p - I'm guessing he means click.. maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `$("label[for!='other']")` to select the labels that do not have the `for` attribute set to 'other'.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("label:not([for='other'])")
```

or:

```
$("label[for!='other']")
```